# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying this for a last few days. I have downloaded a sample from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection). I have replaced the model `Detect.tflite` and label file and put my own instead, but ended up with several errors as shown below:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 1080000 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 270000 bytes.

And this one:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 1917, 4] and a Java object with shape [1, 10,4].

Kindly help.

Comment: With what did you replace the model? Can you share both versions, please?

Comment: The sample have detect.tflite model and label.txt. I have changed that with my .tflite model and label.txt

Comment: please update your question with the contents you changed.

Comment: It seems, you have changed the data with different dimensions, There is mismatch in the input shape [older and the new]

Comment: @Gaurav, might be the model have done so. Don't know where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: The question is too broad and does not include meaningful information to proceed with investigation. `have downloaded a sample` is not helpful as it contains both ios and android code. `have replaced the model .. put my own instead` is not clear what the new model is and how you came by it and why you replaced it. `ended up with several errors` is not helpful as does not contain information on how to reproduce the issue. Otherwise your model and what it does with input does not fit expectations of sample code as it produces shape `[1, 1917, 4]` instead of `[1, 10, 4]`

Comment: Yes it is very broad but can be very simple for those who are well aware about it and this is posted with keeping them as context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is all about the mismatch of input tensor from the model and the array we mention in the code(Android).

Changing in the input tensor did the trick and model worked well in this case.

The input tensor shape array was changed to  [1, 10,4] from python side.

Comment: Hi Vir, Im wondering how you managed the "changing in the input tensor" part? Im still seeing the " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with 2076672 bytes from a Java Buffer with 1080000 bytes." issue on my App.

Comment: @PabloO just FYI, You need to change quantisize from 1 to 4, or image size to the model size

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using teachable machine to generate my `.tflite` file, and when you need to install it you'll have punch of options like:
`Floating point` or `Quantized` or `EdgeTPU`.

And Floating point was the only one which works without causing the issue mentioned.