# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 1] and a Java object with shape [1, 2]

Tags: tensorflow, flutter

I am connecting Custom ML Model with flutter andriod application,but i have got this error while running this App.

I have attached Error Image Here
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqCdS.png)

Flutter Code for App is [Code](https://github.com/tejas2198/ML-App/blob/master/main.dart)

please help me to solve this Error
Thank you

Comment: So you say `numResults: 2` but maybe the model only returns 1 result?

Comment: I did what you have said(numResult :2) but again i am getting same Error.

Comment: Please refer answers section of these SO links may helps you [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393407/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-copy-between-a-tensorflowlite-tensor) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929312/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-copy-between-a-tensorflowlite-tensor).Thanks